# loading a jar file at runtime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker

Tags: kotlin, plugins, jar, runtime, classloader

I have `foo.jar` that contains `Foo`:

```kotlin
class Foo: Bar { ... }
```

`bar.jar` that contains Bar:

```kotlin
abstract class Bar { ... }
```

Then I have `baz.jar` that loads `Foo` dynamically:

```kotlin
val jarFile = JarFile("./foo.jar")
val e: Enumeration<JarEntry> = jarFile.entries()

val urls = arrayOf(URL("jar:file:foo.jar!/"))
val cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls)

Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader = cl // With or without same result.

val list = mutableListOf<Class<*>>()
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
val je: JarEntry = e.nextElement()
...
cl.loadClass(className)
```

And run it as follow:

```sh
java -cp ./bar.jar -jar ./baz.jar
```

First, I'm confused that I get a "ClassNotFoundException" even though `bar.jar` is in the classpath.
I get around this problem by loading dynamically `./bar.jar` before `./foo.jar` as in the code above.

Then now I get `NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/markers/KMappedMarker`

The kotlin runtime is already packed in the `foo.jar`.

```sh
jar -xvf foo/build/libs/foo-1.0.jar | grep std
extracted: BOOT-INF/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar
```

I've also created a fat-jar for `bar.jar` so it contains `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-reflect` but I'm still getting the same error.

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested I finally make it working by changing:

```kotlin
val cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls)
```

to this:

```kotlin
val cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls, this::class.java.classLoader)
```

No need for fat-jar nor additional `-cp` options.